# Default kernel boot parameter on Red Hat 6 / CentOS 6

Tags: linux, redhat, grub

I would like to understand if, and how, it is possible to configure default kernel boot parameters on Red Hat 6 / CentOS 6 (grub legacy bootloader).

I very well understand how to manually configure the required parameters: I simply have to edit /etc/grub.conf and edit the specific stanza. However, a similar configuration will not last a kernel update: the new stanza will be configured with *default* kernel boot parameters.

Newer system (eg: RHEL7) use grub2 and the /etc/default/grub file and the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX variable to solve that specific problem.

So my question is: it is possible to specify system-wide, default kernel boot parameters and let these parameters to be the default settings for new kernels (updated via YUM/RPM) also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New kernel will inherit kernel cmdline from the last running kernel, so if you make changes to grub.conf, they will persist kernel upgrade.

You can see that by running:

```
rpm -q --scripts kernel
```

Relevant lines in RPM scripts are:

```
NEWKERNARGS=""
(/sbin/grubby --info=`/sbin/grubby --default-kernel`) 2>/dev/null | grep -q crashkernel
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
        NEWKERNARGS="--kernel-args="crashkernel=auto""
fi
```

So, only thing that RPM upgrade does is add crashkernel=auto if it's missing from kernel arguments.